# Como converter 2,22292E+12 para 2222921601281

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um método que retorna um float (mas posso mudar esse retorno para o outro se for preciso)

```
 float mmc(int a, int b)
    {
        float num1, num2, x, y, mmc = 0;
        
        num1 = a;
        num2 =b;
        x = num1;
        y = num2;
        while (num1 != num2)
        {
            if (num1 > num2)
            {
                num1 = num1 - num2;
            }
            else
            {
                num2 = num2 - num1;
            }
        }

        float resultado =(x * y) / num1;
        mmc = (x * y) / num1;
        return mmc;
    }
```

Ao passar valores altos (o que vai ocorrer sempre) ele retorna letras e números. A formula está certa, no Excel está batendo, mas lá eu formato a célula para numero e ai obtenho o resultado correto.
**exemplo
resultado do mmc retornado = 2,22292E+12  e como eu preciso 2222921601281.**

Como converto ou trato esse valor no c# ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar `decimal` ao invés de `float` para obter um resultado mais preciso. Floats e doubles trabalham com arredondamento de valores, portanto não seriam uma opção viável para calcular o mmc, pois você precisa de um número exato, e não um arredondado.

Ex: MMC(889787, 977541)

`Output em float: 8,698034E+12`

`Output em decimal: 8698033627457`

A função ficaria assim:

```
decimal mmc(int a, int b)
{
    decimal num1, num2, x, y, mmc = 0;

    num1 = a;
    num2 = b;
    x = num1;
    y = num2;
    while (num1 != num2)
    {
        if (num1 > num2)
        {
            num1 = num1 - num2;
        }
        else
        {
            num2 = num2 - num1;
        }
    }

    decimal resultado = (x * y) / num1;
    mmc = (x * y) / num1;
    return mmc;
}
```

Comment: o valor bateu, agradeço  a ajuda @Natan Fernandes

Comment: Eu que agradeço!